# Why is \pgfkeysnovalue not settable?

Tags: pgfkeys

## TL;DR

Why is it impossible to set a key in `pgfkeys` to `\pgfkeysnovalue`?

```latex
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/bar/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue,
  % ...
  % This will not work
  /foo/bar=\pgfkeysnovalue
}
```

## Main question

I have a problem understanding an issue with `pgfkeys`. I want to have an option that is resetting itself. I wanted to use the `\pgfkeysnovalue` macro: If no value is passed to the key, it should be `\pgfkeysnovalue`, otherwise the corresponding value.

This did not work as expected so I broke it down to an MWE. I put the code below.

Here, `/foo` is some namespace and `/foo/bar` is the parameter in question. Using `\testCall{}` I can add the optional parameter `bar=...` to set the value for that invocation.

Upon the call, the current value is stored in a macro `\mymacro` and typed out.

I get the following result when running the MWE:

```
Result: 
Result: 3
Result: 2
Result: 3
3
Result: 3
Result: 3
Result: 2
Result: 3
```

Note that the first block is as expected: `\pgfkeysnovalue` is expanded to the empty string. Then during the first run, the value is reset (here to `3` to show the problem), which is output on the second and fourth lines. In the third line, the default is overwritten.

It is strange that the `3` in the fifth line is output. That should be a pure assignment.

Starting at the sixth line, one would expect the same block to repeat. But the first line of the second block is different, the 3 is still stored in the key, obviously.

When replacing the call to `\pgfkeys` for the fifth line by `\pgfkeyssetvalue` as indicated in the comment in the MWE, it works as expected.

Why cannot `\pgfkeys` be used here?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
    /foo/.is family,/foo,
    bar/.initial=\pgfkeysnovalue,
    call/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{
            /foo,
            bar/.get=\mymacro,
            % This should be \pgfkeysnovalue but here for sake of presentation some dummy value "3"
            bar=3,
        }
        Result: \mymacro \par
    }
}
\newcommand{\testCall}[1]{\pgfkeys{/foo,#1,call}}
\begin{document}
\testCall{}
\testCall{}
\testCall{bar=2}
\testCall{}

\pgfkeys{/foo/bar=\pgfkeysnovalue}
% \pgfkeyssetvalue{/foo/bar}{\pgfkeysnovalue}

\testCall{}
\testCall{}
\testCall{bar=2}
\testCall{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define a macro that expands to empty and is (named) different to `\pgfkeysnovalue`. `\pgfkeysnovalue` is more or less one of `pgfkeys`' internal macros hence it's better to not use or rely on it in user code.

Answer (score 1):

I was just forwarded to this [change in the sourcecode of PGF](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/2a107415eda3f3f7ff640fb7d686363f7257057f#diff-65d9bc1a3f85d7699f389cf3538febf4129aae829321bd1b4bf60a1e05bea207R314-R323).

It seems that to allow for simpler reading of values, it is now allowed to fetch the value with `\pgfkeys{/foo/bar}`. The latter is internally parsed as `\pgfkeys{/foo/bar=\pgfkeysnovalue}` which was redefined as a special case to output the content of the key `/foo/bar`.

I ended using a dedicated `\newif` to set a flag if the parameter was to be used or not. Something like this:

```latex
\newif\ifbarpresent
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/bar present/.is if=barpresent,
  /foo/bar value/.initial=0,
  /foo/bar/.style={
    /foo/bar present=true,
    /foo/bar value=#1
  }
}
```

And to use it I did

```latex
\ifbarpresent
The value of bar: \pgfkeys{/foo/bar value}
\fi
```